# CritSec.h not existent (Win 8.1)

Tags: c++, include

I have this sample code I'm currently using to write a dll in c++.

In this [file](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096/sourcecode?fileId=98988&pathId=1543041529) critsec.h is included.

However on my system (Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit) Visual Studio 2013 CE can't find the source file.
Am I missing some sort of SDK or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [project file](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096/sourcecode?fileId=98988&pathId=606873395) belonging you your example file, you see the following additional include directories (reformatted for better reading):

```
<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories);
    $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory);
    ..\..\Common
</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
```

And indeed, in `..\..\Common`, you will find [CritSec.h](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096/sourcecode?fileId=98988&pathId=522775072)

Answer (score 0):

How do you include this? There are two ways. If you you use #include "something.h" the file has to be at the same location where youre .cpp is. If you use #include  than the header has to be at a directory in visaul studio.

Comment: like in the example with "#include <CritSec.h>"

Comment: Sorry, i dont use Visual Studio. But if you copy the header next to .cpp file or .c and use #include "CritSec.h" it should work fine.

Comment: If you use #include <CritSec.h>, the file should be here: \visual c++\include\CritSec.h
This isn't for sure, i just did google it.